# Ansible: list all hosts to add it to 'hosts' file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I set up group of test VMs (with pure Debian) to play with, all of them are on test network so it is self-contained group of VM. These VMs be destroyed soon so I don't want to add its names to DNS while I need to have them communicate oven hostnames.

Is there any way I can form `/etc/hosts` files on these VMs based on hosts IPs from Ansible `hosts` file?

I can set hostnames like that

```
192.168.0.5 myhostname=host01.local
192.168.0.6 myhostname=host02.local
```

so I think I can somehow form `/etc/hosts` like that:

```
{{ ip }} {{ myhostname }}
```

but can archive that. I think I can iterate over `group['all']` and use `lineinfile` to add lines to `/etc/hosts`, but it won't work for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inventory_file` variable to get the path filename of the hosts file:

> Also available, `inventory_dir` is the pathname of the directory holding Ansible’s inventory host file, `inventory_file` is the pathname and the filename pointing to the Ansible’s inventory host file.

[Reference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

You can read its variables with something like:

```
tasks:
  - local_action: shell cat {{ inventory_file }}
    register: result
```

As recommended [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data). More on [local actions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) here.

You can then use [jinja filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#jinja2-filters) and [loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html) to use the variable.